# JSTL - preselect dropwdown value

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a java variable coming from an external system. I need to preselect the dorpdown based on the value received.

I am trying to test the below code but still not working.

//String myPaymentType = "I";

//Drop down has values as "",I,R,IR

```
<select name="paymentType" id="paymentType" class="form-control">
       <c:forEach var="paymentType" items="${paymentTypes}">
        <option <c:if test='${paymentType.paymentValue == myPaymentType}' >selected</c:if>
          value="${paymentType.paymentValue}" >${paymentType.paymentDesc}</option>
      </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

//PaymentType.Java

```
 private String paymentValue;
private String paymentDesc;
public PaymentType(String paymentValue, String paymentDesc) {
    super();
    this.paymentValue = paymentValue;
    this.paymentDesc = paymentDesc;
}
public String getPaymentValue() {
    return paymentValue;
}
public void setPaymentValue(String paymentValue) {
    this.paymentValue = paymentValue;
}
public String getPaymentDesc() {
    return paymentDesc;
}
public void setPaymentDesc(String paymentDesc) {
    this.paymentDesc = paymentDesc;
}
```

//PaymentTYpes is an ArraList of PaymentType objects

```
    PaymentType paymentType1 = new PaymentType("","Select Payment Type");
        PaymentType paymentType2 = new PaymentType("I","Initial");
        PaymentType paymentType3 = new PaymentType("R","Recurring");
        PaymentType paymentType4 = new PaymentType("IR","Intial & Recurring");
        PaymentType paymentType5 = new PaymentType("O","Onetime");

        paymentTypes.add(0,paymentType1);
        paymentTypes.add(1,paymentType2);
        paymentTypes.add(2,paymentType3);
        paymentTypes.add(3,paymentType4);
        paymentTypes.add(4,paymentType5);
```

//HTML view source

```
    <select name="paymentType" id="paymentType" class="form-control">                       <option  value="" >Select Payment Type</option>
       <option  value="I" >Initial</option>
        <option  value="R" >Recurring</option>
       <option  value="IR" >Intial & Recurring</option>
       <option  value="O" >Onetime</option>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //It should be 
   request.setAttribute("myPaymentType","I");

 //Not
   String myPaymentType = "I";
```

I still have a question, how we can validate againest a variable using jstl? Do we have to have variable in only request object?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming on java-side

```
String myPaymentType = "I";
String paymentTypes = "-;I;R;IR";
```

in JSP the following should work (ok, it will be converted to java, too)

```
<select name="paymentType">
   <c:forEach var="pt" items="${paymentTypes}">
    <option ${pt == myPaymentType ? 'selected' : ''} >${pt}</option>
   </c:forEach>
</select>
```

if you need separate values for data and display, you need to supply an array of pairs.
Something like

```
 class Pair {
    private String data;
    private String display;
    public Pair (String pDisplay, String pData) {
       data = pData;
       display = pDisplay;
    }
    public String getData () {
       return data;
    }
    public String getDisplay () {
       return display;
    }
 }

 Pair[] paymentTypes = new Pair [] {new Pair ("one", "1"), new Pair ("two", "2")};
```

Then you could do

```
<select name="paymentType">
   <c:forEach var="pt" items="${paymentTypes}">
    <option ${pt.data == myPaymentType ? 'selected' : ''} >${pt.display}</option>
   </c:forEach>
</select>
```

(Disclaimer, written without IDE, may have errors)
This proposal is not the only possible solution.

Comment: Thsnks for the explination. All I need to make this line work. ${paymentType.paymentValue == myPaymentType ? 'selected' : ''}. But it is still not working.

Comment: Please supply the java code for `paymentTypes`. I guess there is something wrong

Comment: updated my post. Iam able to display values and descriptions with my original code. Problem with only preselecting.

Comment: I made it work buddy. Problem is the muPaymentType has to be in the request object. I am not sure if it can chec kwith a variable.