# Spring add default value to form:options in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Is it possible to select some default value in my dropdown list, which is in my .jsp implemented like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <form:label path="month">Select month</form:label>
   <form:select path="month" class="form-control">
   <form:options items="${months}" />
   </form:select>
</div>
```

And in my controller I have method:

```
private List<String> getMonths() {
    List<String> months = new ArrayList<String>();
    months.add("January");
    months.add("February");
    months.add("March");
    months.add("April");
    months.add("May");
    months.add("June");
    months.add("July");
    months.add("August");
    months.add("September");
    months.add("October");
    months.add("November");
    months.add("December");
    return months;
}
```

and it is added to .jsp like this:

```
model.addAttribute("months", getMonths());
```

I need to have pre-selected some value after loading a page, for ex. "March".

Comment: Maybe look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711670/jstl-preselect-dropwdown-value

Comment: You already did set selected value for the dropdown. Spring will use value in property "month" of the Model as selected value. All you need to do is set "month" property a value from your Java action method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through the list using forEach and then use if condition to choose whichever month you want to be selected as default. See below a sample:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:forEach items="${months}" var="month">
        <c:when test="${month == 'March'}">
            <option value="${month}" selected>${month}</option>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
          <option value="${month}">${month}</option>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:forEach>
  </c:choose>
```

Comment: Now dropdown shows only one value: March, not other months.

Comment: I updated the answer, the previous answer had one if condition hence, it only printed the option when the condition was satisfied and did not print for other values, which is why you had only March.

Comment: I was getting an error without <c:choose> tag, so I added it, now it's again displaying all values, but ' March  ' is not selected.

Comment: <c:choose> does not iterate through your list. <c:forEach> iterates through each element of the list and then assign it to **month** variable then <c:when> and <c:otherwise> is applied to the value of variable month. What was the error?

Comment: I got this:

    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/myTeams.jsp at line 111

108:           <form:select path="month" class="form-control">
109:           <%-- <form:options items="${months}" /> --%>
110: <c:forEach items="${months}" var="month">
111:     <c:when test="${month == 'March'}">
112:         <option value="${month} selected">${month}</option>
113:     </c:when>
114:     <c:otherwise>

    Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Illegal use of &lt;when&gt;-style tag without &lt;choose&gt; as its direct parent.

Comment: replace the line inside <option value="${month} selected">${month}</option>  with <option value="${month}" selected>${month}</option> .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94752/discussion-between-raf-and-lenusska1414).